# Is it safe to call <math.h> functions by reference?

Tags: c++, function, math, reference

Please, tell me is it safe to call math functions the following way:

```
map<string,double(*)<double> func_map = { {"sin", &std::sin } ... }
...
double arg = 2.9;
double res = func_map["sin"](arg);
```

Comment: Why call them that way?

Comment: I'm using RPN to parse math expressions (that could contain math functions as well). Using map to access these functions is much shorter than using lots of "if .. else if ...else if".

Comment: Be careful: It looks to me like this is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction) in C++20.

Comment: Though declaration of your map is not correct, the function pointer declaration should look like `double(*)(double)`

Comment: @NathanPierson  The changes in C++20 make the effects *unspecified* or (in some cases) ill-formed - not undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking the addresses of functions in the standard library not on the [*Designated addressable functions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Designated_addressable_functions) list leads to unspecified behavior (since at least C++20). `std::sin` and the other `<cmath>` functions are not on that list so, to be safe, wrap them up in functors, like lambdas:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, double(*)(double)> func_map = {
        {"sin", [](double x) { return std::sin(x); }},
        {"cos", [](double x) { return std::cos(x); }},
    };
}
```

---

> is it safe to call math functions the following way:
>
> ```
> double res = func_map["sin"](arg);
> ```

No, if the function you aim to call is not present in `func_map`, using the subscript [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) would first insert a `double(*)(double)` pointing at `nullptr` into the map and then return that `nullptr`. Calling `nullptr(arg)` would lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). To make it safe you can do a couple of things:

- Make `func_map` `const`. This prevents you from using any functions potentially inserting something in the map, like the subscript operator.
- Use `func_map.at("sin")(arg);` to get an exception ([`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range)) if the function doesn't exist in the map. You can safely catch that and print a message to the user:

  ```cpp
  try {
      double res = func_map.at("sin")(arg);
      std::cout << res << '\n';
  } catch (const std::out_of_range& ex) {
      std::cout << "unknown function\n";
  }
  ```
- If you don't want exceptions for unknown functions, you can use the member function `find` instead:

  ```cpp
  if(auto fit = func_map.find("sin"); fit != func_map.end()) {
      double res = fit->second(arg);
      std::cout << res << '\n';
  } else {
      std::cout << "unknown function\n";
  }
  ```